# helpers for angular providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some helper functions, which I need several times at providers (outisde $get) and at config phase. When I don't want to write it at global scope I see two solutions:

- A own helper provider:

  ```
  app.provider('helper', function() {
    this.help = function() {
      // helper functionality
    }

    this.$get = function() {};
  });

  app.config(function(helperProvider) {
    helperProvider.help();
  });
  ```
- The helper as constant:

  ```
  app.constant('help', function() {
    // helper functionality
  });

  app.config(function(help) {
    help();
  });
  ```

I don't like the provider solution, because I always have to use the suffix provider when I want to use it and I need an unused $get method.
So I uses the constant solution at the moment.

But now I have a new problem: I have an additional helper which I needs at the helper. The `angular.constant` is not initialized with an injector.

When the other helper (let's name it metaHelper) is at an other module (in the exmaple helperModule), than I can use `angular.injector`:

```
app.constant('help', function() {
  var metaHelper = angular.injector(['helperModule', 'ng']).get('metaHelper');
  metaHelper();
});
```

That I do at the moment but it feels wrong. And what is, when I have at the future "metaHelpers" in the same module? What is the best practice for provider/config helper at angular?

Thanks

Comment: You should base your code on official documentation for providers: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. Just add provider suffix and you are done. Remeber that you will need suffix only in config secion of your module, after configuration you may refer to service provided by provider using simple name

Comment: yes I can drop the suffix after config phase, but the point is, that I need the utilities only at the config phase. And the "provieded service" is not needed too. So the needed $get implementation is only a stub which I don't like too.